# Find out if a point belongs to the shape (or lies on its border).

Tags: geometry

There is a figure shown [in the image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DYyVs.png).
$a$ is the radius of the circle (the circle lies at point $(0, 0)$), the equation of the line is defined as $y=kx$.
There is also a set of random points.
For all points, I need to determine whether they lie **in the given shape** (or **on its border**, or **outside the shape**).
Please help me to derive the formula. I will be very grateful.

Comment: The area inside the circle has the equation $x^2 + y^2 < a^2$.

Comment: $\{ x, y \}\ {\rm s.t.}\ x^2 + y^2 \leq a^2 \wedge y \leq k x$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Any point $(\alpha,\beta)$ will be inside the circle iff $$\alpha^2+\beta^2\lt a^2$$ and below the line iff $$ \beta \lt k\alpha$$ so you need both of these conditions to be true for a point to lie inside the region you shaded. Reverse the inequality signs for outside points. For the point to lie on the boundary, you need either $$\alpha^2+\beta^2=a^2 \ \text{and} \ \beta \le k\alpha$$ or $$\beta=k\alpha \ \text{and} \  \alpha^2+\beta^2 \le a^2$$

Comment: You really saved me. Thank you so much, everything is working perfectly!